# Why does Ruby only allow to refer to methods by symbols when calling to_proc on them?

Tags: ruby, symbols, proc

This works:

```
strings = ["1", "2", "3"]
nums = strings.map(&:to_i)
```

We see that & (*to_proc* method) applied to a Symbol object is turned into a block.
This, however, doesn't work:

```
strings = ["1", "2", "3"]
nums = strings.map(&to_i)
nums = strings.map("to_i".to_sym.to_proc) #...neither does this
```

Why doesn't it work? Isn't there any alternative way to write the code above? I'm confused because there are two ways to access a method of a class:

```
"1".method(:to_i).call #works as well as
"1".method("to_i").call
```

So the method's name can be accessed either by symbol or a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the following valid Ruby example:

```
"to_i".to_sym.to_proc.call("1")
```

To call `#to_proc` on a Symbol creates a proc that receive one parameter: the object that should receive an invocation of the method named by the symbol. Something like this:

```
->(object) {
  object.send(:to_i)
}
```

What the `&` do is to pass the block returned by `#to_proc` as a proper invocation block to the method being called. When used with `Enumerable#map`, the final result is that the passed
block will be invoked for each element on the collection and receive
the current iteration element being passed as parameter to the block.

So the `["1", "2"].map(&:to_i)` syntax is a shortcut to something like
this:

```
block = ->(el) {
  el.send(:to_i)
}

["1", "2"].map &block
```

### About your examples:

When you try to call `&to_i` in your example, Ruby will try to invoke
a variable or method named `to_i`. Since it doesn't exists in the
scope (it is a method of each `String` in the `Array`, not in the "global" scope), it'll generate an error.

About the other example: `"to_i".to_sym.to_proc` will transform the
`:to_i` into a proc that when invoked with one parameter, will try to
call the method named after the symbol (`:to_i`) against the target
parameter. This means that you could use the `&` to transform the proc
into a "invocation block":

```
["1", "2"].map(&"to_i".to_sym.to_proc)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = strings.map(&to_i)
```

does not work because `to_i` is not defined in the main environment.

```
nums = strings.map("to_i".to_sym.to_proc)
```

does not work because a `Proc` instance is not a block. A block is not even an object.

You can write:

```
nums = strings.map(&"to_i".to_sym)
```